# How to implement the IS-A relationship in Hibernate Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have 3 table: Account, Doctor, Patient

- Account ( **User_id**, fullname, email, password )
- Patient (**Patient_id**, healthrecord_id, insurance_id )
- Doctor  ( **Doctor_id**, professional_statement, clinic_id)

Patient_id and Doctor_id are primary key and also foreign_key which referred to User_id in Account table. I think it is one-on-one relationship for Account-Patient, Account Doctor. I do not know how to implement it in Hibernate Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}
```

create the super class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

}
```

And extend it with your entities.

```
@Entity
public class Doctor extends User {

    private String name;

    private String email;

}
```

you need to create an (Absctract) class User and extend with 
Patient and Doctor as well.You only need to define the `id` field on the base entity.
You also have to provide getters and setters to all classes. I suggest using the `lombok` annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter`

Or you can map them one by one to the Account entity.

Hit me up if something isn't clear!

Comment: Can I do simpler by using OneToOne relationship. I will add another user_id to both Doctor and Patient table and make it as foreign key of the Account table. Is it possible? Like Account (User_id, field 1, field 2) and Doctor( Doctor_id, User_id, f1, f2 ,...) and Patient (Patient_id, User_id, f3, f4,...)

Comment: Yes of course. In that case you won't need the `abstract User class`.